# Ruby on Rails - Pass ID from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, controller, associations

I have two models. First is Taxirecord and second is Carpark. Each Taxirecord may have its own Carpark. I have a problem with passing taxirecord_id to Carpark record. I have route

```
car_new GET    /taxidetail/:taxirecord_id/carpark/new(.:format) carparks#new
```

And i want to pass :taxirecord_id, which is id of taxirecord that im editing, to my create controller. 
My carpark model:

```
class Carpark < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :taxirecord
end
```

In controller im finding taxirecord_id by find function based on param :taxirecord_id, but id is nil when create is called. Can you please help me to find out what Im doing wrong and how Can I solve this problem? Thanks for any help!

My carpark controller

```
class CarparksController < ApplicationController
    def new
            @car = Carpark.new
    end
    def create
            @car = Carpark.new(carpark_params, taxirecord_id: Taxirecord.find(params[:taxirecord_id]))
            if @car.save
                    flash[:notice] = "Zaznam byl ulozen"
                    redirect_to root_path
            else
                    flash[:notice] = "Zaznam nebyl ulozen"
                    render 'new'
            end

    end
private def carpark_params
                params.require(:carpark).permit(:car_brand, :car_type, :driver_name, :driver_tel)
        end

end
```

Comment: What's in your controller? and how're you performing the request to that route?

Comment: Please **show your full code**, not just a description of your code. I suspect the issue is that you are not calling `permit` with the necessary attributes, but I am unable to answer your question properly without seeing the code!

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to figure out what you mean here. You need to describe what you desire a bit better. Showing more code would probably help. Maybe a before and after case as well.

Comment: EDIT: added controller

Comment: I want to add carpark, which belongs to taxirecord associated by taxirecord_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally get it work
Ive added `<%=link_to 'New Carpark', {:controller => "carparks", :action => "new", :taxirecord_id => @taxi_record.id }%>`
to my taxirecord form and to carpark form `<%= hidden_field_tag :taxirecord_id, params[:taxirecord_id] %>`
And to my carpark controller : `@carpark.taxirecord_id = params[:taxirecord_id]`
Thanks everyone for great support and help!

Comment: Glad it's working - take a quick look at Rails routing (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for the link format - there'll be an auto-generated route you can use in the `link_to` field that's the conventional approach.

If you get the time, have a play with my answer - I personally feel it's the 'Railsy' way to do this :) 

Also, if your hidden field's working as it should be, you should be able to user `carpark_params` to pass it in, without the extra line assigning it. Good luck with the rest of the project!

Comment: Finally, I've no idea why someone's down voting your question - +1 from me :)

Comment: Many thanks @SRack. I really appreciate your support and help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd lean towards using something like:

```
before_action :assign_taxirecord   

...

private

def assign_taxirecord
  @taxirecord = TaxiRecord.find(params[:taxirecord_id])
end
```

And then in the create action:

```
def create
  @car = @taxirecord.build_carpark(carpark_params)
  ...
end
```

Obviously there's a little tailoring needed to your requirements (i.e. for what actions the `before_action` is called), but I hope that helps!

Comment: Welcome! I've jotted that down from memory, and believe the `build_carpark` method is created automatically in a has_one / belongs_to method. If it's not the case, have a tinker / please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

No need to send taxirecord id.

```
class Carpark < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :taxirecord
end


class Taxirecord < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :carpark
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :taxirecords do 
    resources :carparks
  end
end


for new taxirecord
 t = Taxirecord.new(:registration => "efgh", :description =>"test")

for new carpark
 t.create_carpark(:description=>"abcd")


#=> #<Carpark id: 2, taxirecord_id: 2, description: "abcd", created_at: "2017-10-12 10:55:38", updated_at: "2017-10-12 10:55:38">
```

Comment: Why it cant be like this:
Taxirecord edit form:
`<%=link_to 'New Carpark', new_carpark_path(@taxi_record)%>`

and in Carpark Controller
`@carpark.taxirecord_id = @taxi_record.id`
?
Thanks!

Comment: Please paste your models controllers and routes code

Comment: add taxirecord_id in carpark_params 1st